# Android TablaLayout and NavigationDrawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-tablelayout, navigation-drawer

I have a two problems and struggle for a few days. I am not sure what the right way is.

1. I want to combine a tab layout with a view pager containing three fragments (the tab layout and the view pager are the home screen) and a navigation drawer.
   And I think that everything you can navigate to from the drawer should be a fragment accept settings or something similar. 
   So should I let the tab layout in the layout of the main activities layout or should I put the this layout also in a fragment (so view pager with fragments inside a so calling home fragment)?
2. When starting the app I check if the user is logged in and if he is download data from Firebase. I do this in another fragment (data fragment) there I setretaininstance to true.
   So currently one of the tab fragments needs the data from Firebase but soon all of them will need it.
   How do I pass the data (Lists) from the data fragment to the tab fragments or the so called home fragment and then to the tabs. 
   I already tried interfaces but I don't know how to handle confirmation changes.

Considering the two problems or the combination of both how would you solve this / which design approach is better only use fragments or let the home screen inside the main activity and change the view when the user navigates from the drawer to fragment?

PS. I will add some code as soon as possible.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

TabLayout and the ViewPager should be in the Activity layout since it makes more sense, as the Activity manages the Fragments. Also, navigation drawer should navigates through Activities, and Activities between Fragments. Again, that's the logical thing for a decent code organization, and it prevents repetitions in layout (AKA more than one button to navigate to the same fragment).

For the Firebase issue, I suggest you start the call in the Activity, and then call a function in all fragments with the retrieved information. Something like this:

```
new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(MyFragment f : mFragmentList)
            f.addData(dataSnapshot);
    }
}
```

If you really want the Fragment to make the call to Firebase, then you can create you own Event and Listener set.

```
public class SnapshotRetrievedEvent {
    private static List<SnapshotRetrievedListener> listeners = new ArrayList<>();

    public static void addListener(SnapshotRetrievedListener listener){
        listeners.add(listener);
    }

    public static void notify(DataSnapshot snapshot) {
        for(SnapshotRetrievedListener listener : listeners)
            listener.onSnapshotRetrived( snapshot );
    }
}

public interface SnapshotRetrievedListene {
    void onSnapshotRetrieved(DataSnapshot snapshot);
}
```

Then in your Fragment waiting for the snapshot, you add the listener like this:

```
SnapshotRetrievedEvent.addListener(
    new SnapshotRetrievedListener(){
        @Override
        public void onSnapshotRetrieved(DataSnapshot snapshot){
           // Do stuff
        }
    }
);
```

onSnapshotRetrieved will be called when you call `SnapshotRetrievedEvent.notify(snapshot)` in your other Fragment.

Hope this helps

Comment: I thought you were supposed to use fragments with a navigation drawer to have a mod fluent UX?

Comment: It does seem popular indeed. I think that it depends on the application itself and what you want to do with it. I still think the ViewPager with TabLayout should be exclusive to the navigation drawer since the TabLayout is there specially for navigation.